# How to work on MS Word [.doc] files in c# to edit,create or do changes to it

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

How to create, edit or save a word file using c#.net. Plz suggest me the libraries and necessary tools needed to work on Word files. I need solutions for the below questions:

> How to access and read and interpret word[.doc] files in .net?
>   How Code is to be intergrated onto the source file?
>   How to represent this word file in a standard format?
>   Suggest me some related web sites.
>   Also if source code of such similar projects on word.

Comment: There are many ways to do Word automation (and of course there are also possibilities to edit Word document without Word). Can you provide more context so that we possibly can provide a meaningful answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Word 2007, word documents can be saved as [Open Xml](https://web.archive.org/web/20191118184949/http://openxmldeveloper.org:80/default.aspx). You can use the [Open Xml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en) to edit/save/etc...

Even more info:
[Open Xml Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/)
[Intro to Word XML](https://web.archive.org/web/20160115143111/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/07/05/intro-to-word-xml-part-1-simple-word-document.aspx)
[Word Xml format walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb266220%28v=office.12%29)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to access the relevant types and methods. If you have access to C# and .NET 4 the syntax is a lot nicer, than it used to be from C#.

E.g. to open word you need to do something along these lines

```
     var word = new Word.Application();

     word.Documents.Add();
     Document = word.Documents[1];

     word.Visible = true;
```

For more info, please [check the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/) is a decent tool. It's a great API if you're doing enterprise development but it might be a little pricey if you're just working on some pet projects at home (there's a free download with an unlimited evaluation period -- you only need a license for deployment). For casual/home development, I'd recommend Microsoft's OpenXML SDK (if you only need to support 2007 or beyond) or you could always use automation via the Interop assemblies.